# Google App Script > Spreadsheet > get row id?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

Besides the row index, which you can get using `Range.getRowIndex()`, is there any unique identifier for a row in a spreadsheet?  If yes, what's the API for this?  I don't see it in the Google docs.

I'm weary to lean on the row index because a user might swap or delete rows manually, and there goes comparisons...

I want to be able to uniquely identify a form submission.

Comment: Maybe include some code to show how you're using it

Comment: If a user can delete rows and you not trust it, they can also edit any of the form response values. What are you comparing to what?

Answer (score 2):

There's a unique form response id that you can set in the row...

e.response.getId();

Where 'e' is the object being passed to your form submit function.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to retrieve this if you were not catching this on-submit? I guess I can fallback on a UUID generator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering such an old query, but the Googles turned it up as an answer to my own question (how are form responses and spreadsheet rows related).

Given the form ID, it's possible to use the Google Apps Script Forms Service to get all of the responses, and for each one to get it's ID and timestamp, and use the Spreadsheet Service to store the ID in the row with matching timestamp:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var responses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    var response = responses[i];
    Logger.log(response.getId());
    Logger.log(response.getTimestamp());
    // use Spreadsheet API to get matching row and store ID
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/